# jQuery: Only select first level childnodes

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I'm trying to get something to work what should be fairly easy with jQuery.
All I want is to select the sibblings of the selected node, and **NOT** the children of a sibbling!

```
<div id="test">
    <p>First Paragraph
        <p class='border2'>SUB paragraph
            <p class='border3'>SUB SUB paragraph</p>
        </p>
    </p>
    <p>Second Paragraph</p>
    <p>Third Paragraph</p>
    <p>Fourth Paragraph</p>
</div>
```

At this moment I've tried a lot of different things, but they are not behaving as expected. I tried e.g.:

- `$("div").find("p").andSelf().addClass("border");`
- `$("div > p").addClass("border");`
- `$("div p:first").nextAll().andSelf().addClass("border");`
- `$("#test ~ p").addClass("border");`

My code snippet can be found at [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EPmLh/).

Comment: For some very odd reason, Chrome's devtools sees all of them as level 1 `<p>`s. Try validating your code validator.w3.org

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You won't be able to because your markup is invalid.

You can't have a `<p>` nested in a `<p>` so the browser is kicking the nested `p`s out.

[Here's your fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EPmLh/2/) but with updated CSS to show that they're no longer nested.

You can only nest *inline* elements in a `<p>`.

Comment: dang it! beat me to it! A well earned +1.

Comment: Geez, how dumb of me! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is caused because

> The P element represents a paragraph. It cannot contain block-level elements (including P itself).

Taken from **[The Specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/text.html#h-9.3.1)**.

The browsers consider each paragraph as a direct child of the original div, as it cannot be contained within a different p. You chose the wrong element to mess with :)